# How to calculate average on star rating system in php

Tags: math

This my input, how i calculate average?

```
5 star - 252
4 star - 124
3 star - 40
2 star - 29
1 star - 33

totally 478
```

Can anyone tell me..

Comment: I think a little more detail is in order if you want to get a real answer. Do you have the values in an array for example? Did you already search php.net for avg ?

Comment: must post on [math.stackoverflow.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) where it would get some hundred downvotes :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
(252*5 + 124*4 + 40*3 + 29*2 + 33*1) / (252 + 124 + 40 + 29 + 33)
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply take average as you do in simple mathematics.

```
(252*5 + 124*4 + 40*3 + 29*2 + 33*1)/478
```